# Arithmetic operations in vhdl. How to multiply std_logic vector by real number?

Tags: vhdl

For school tutorial I need to make a component that receives integer values in the interval 0 to 1000. The output return `S`=`V`*`C`, where `C` depends on:

- `C`=1 when `V` is in range [0,10]
- `C`=0.75 when `V` is in range [11,100]
- `C`=0.3125 when `V` is in range [101,1000]

I tried the code below, but it doesn't compile. I guess, I have a problem with types. How should I program a `real` number to multiply with a `std_logic_vector`?

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity comp1 is
    port(
        V: in std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        S:out std_logic_vector(13 dowto 0));
end comp1;

architecture syn of comp1 is
begin
    process is
        variable c: unsigned(4 downto 0);
        variable r: unsigned(13 downto 0);
    begin
        if unsigned(V) < 11 then
            c:=1;
        elsif unsigned(V) < 101 then
            c:=0.75;
        elsif others =>
            c:=0.3125;
        end if;
        r:=unsigned(V)*C;
        S<=std_logic_vector(r(13 downto 0));
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Comment: `it doesn't work` is not a specific problem description. Please edit your question to show exactly what problem you are seeing.

Comment: Use unsigned intsead of slv, and given those constants I'd recommend using shift+add instead of multiplication. No need for Real at all.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not fully clear: what do you need the code for. Depending on your answer, there are actually multiple solutions.

## Prior problem: representation and rounding

As you already found out, seeing you use `numeric_std`, is that a `std_logic_vector` by itself *doesn't represent any value*. It's just an array of `std_logic` elements. Therefore you should not do any operation of bare `std_logic_vector`s.
Now, by casting the vector to an `unsigned` type, you define it as representing an (unsigned) integer value. But now you get the problem that integers cannot represent fractions. So what's 0.1 in integer? 0. That's easy. But what's 0.9 in integer? Well, that depends on your **rounding scheme**. If you simply truncate the number, then the answer is 0 again. But using standard rounding (+0.5), the answer is 1. You haven't told us what rounding scheme you want (I don't know if you thought about it)

P.s. why is your `S` 14 bits wide? If `V` is 10 bits and the largest factor is 1.0, then `S` will also only need 10 bits...

## Implementations

Let's first define an entity

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity comp1 is
    port(
        V : in  std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
        S : out std_logic_vector(9 downto 0)
        );
end entity;
```

## Real operations

You can just convert everything to floating point (`real`) and perform you operation. This will solve all rounding for you and you have much freedom. The problem is that `real` types are not (yet) supported in synthesis. Still, for a test it works as it should

```
architecture behavior of comp1 is
    signal V_real, S_real : real;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin
    V_real <= real(to_integer(unsigned(V)));

    S_real <=
        V_real when V_real <= 10.0 else
        V_real * 0.75 when V_real <= 100.0
        else V_real * 0.3125;

    S <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(integer(S_real), S'length));
end architecture;
```

## Fixed-point

With VHDL-2008 they tried to bridge the problem of not having point-representation for synthesis, by introducing synthesizable fixed-point packages. When using these packages, you can even select the rounding scheme you want. This is because rounding requires extra resources and is not always necessary. Warning: Use of the packages takes some getting used to.

```
architecture behavior of comp1 is
    use ieee.fixed_pkg.all;
    signal V_fix : ufixed(9 downto 0);
    signal C : ufixed(0 downto -15);
    signal S_fix : ufixed(10 downto -15); -- range of V*C+1
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin
    V_fix <= to_ufixed(V, V_fix);

    C <= to_ufixed(1, C) when V_fix <= 10 else
         to_ufixed(0.75, C) when V_fix <= 100 else
         to_ufixed(0.3125, C);

    S_fix <= V_fix * C;

    S <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(S_fix, S'length));
end architecture;
```

p.s. as mentioned, you need to compile in VHDL-2008 mode for this to work.

## Integer arithmetic

If you look at you multiplication factors, you can see that they can be represented by fractions:

- 0.75 = 3/4
- 0.3125 = 5/16

This mean you can simply use integer arithmetic to perform the scaling.

```
architecture behavior of comp1 is
    signal V_int, S_int : integer range 0 to 1000;
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
begin
    V_int <= to_integer(unsigned(V));

    S_int <=
        V_int when V_int <= 10 else
        V_int*3/4 when V_int <= 100 
        else V_int*5/16;

    S <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(S_int, S'length));
end architecture;
```

*NB* Integer arithmetic has no rounding scheme, thus numbers are truncated!

## Low-level optimizations: Shift-and-add

In the comments Brian referred to using shift and add operations. Going back to the integer arithmetic section of my answer, you see that the denominators are actually powers-of-2, which can be realized using bit-shift operations

- x/4 = x/(2^2) = x>>2 (right shift by 2)
- x/16 = x/(2^4) = x>>4 (rightshift by 4)

At the same time, the numerators can also be realized using bitshift and add operations

- x*3 = x*"11"b => x + x<<1 (left shift by 1)
- x*5 = x*"101"b => x + x<<2 (left shift by 2)

Both can be combined in one operations. Note, although you must remember that left shift will throw away the bits shifted out. This can cause a problem, as the fractions of the values are required for correct results. So you need to add bits to calculate the intermediate results.

```
architecture behavior of comp1 is
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    signal V_uns4, S_uns4 : unsigned(13 downto 0); -- add 4 bits for correct adding
begin
    V_uns4 <= resize(unsigned(V),V_uns4'length);

    S_uns4 <=
        shift_left(V_uns4,4) when V_uns4 <= 10 else
        shift_left(V_uns4,3) + shift_left(V_uns4,2) when V_uns4 <= 100 -- "11" >> 2
        else shift_left(V_uns4,2) + V_uns4; --"101" >> 4

    S <= std_logic_vector(resize(shift_right(S_uns4,4),S'length));
end architecture;
```

This method will likely require the least resourses in synthesis. But is does require low level optimizations, which require additional design effort.

## Testbench

Here's how I tested my code

```
entity comp1_tb is end entity;

library ieee;

architecture tb of comp1_tb is
    use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
    signal V,S : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0);
    use ieee.numeric_std.all;
    signal V_int, S_int : integer range 0 to 1000;
begin
    DUT: entity work.comp1
        port map(
            V => V,
            S => S);

    V <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(V_int, V'length));
    S_int <= to_integer(unsigned(S));

    V_stim : process begin
        V_int <= 1;
        wait for 1 ns;
        assert (S_int = 1) report "S should be 1*1 = 1;" severity warning;
        V_int <= 10;
        wait for 1 ns;
        assert (S_int = 10) report "S should be 10*1 = 10;" severity warning;
        V_int <= 100;
        wait for 1 ns;
        assert (S_int = 75) report "S should be 100*0.75 = 75;" severity warning;
        V_int <= 1000;
        wait for 1 ns;
        assert (S_int = 312 OR S_int = 313) report "S should be 1000*0.3125 = 312 or 313;" severity warning;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Answer (score -2):

1. add V signal to process sensitivity list;
2. use shifting and addititon instead of direct multiplication as Brian said.